# Docker image for tomcat 7.0.55

Tags: docker, tomcat7, dockerfile

We have one of our Java projects with `Tomcat 7.0.55` dependency, I have no liberty to upgrade this.

I want to run this in a container. But when I run, I get **`Apache Tomcat 7.0.55 not found`** in the browser.

In the official tomcat docker hub, I couldn't find this version, is it not supported? Do I have to create that image from scratch? If so, please point me to a good tutorial.

Here is my sample Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:7-jdk
COPY . /app
WORKDIR  /app
RUN javac ... # compilation step

EXPOSE 8088

FROM tomcat:8.0 # I Have tried 7.0.92-jre7 as well
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=0 /app .
CMD  java ... # run the project
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29297790/6309), your Dockerfile should copy your war in the webapps folder of the Tomcat image, instead of trying to run it.

However, there is no tomcat 7.0.55: the [first image](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/commits/1722fc14b4eb66f746a2067739f32d4111f408de/7/jre7-alpine/Dockerfile) was for 7.0.70.

You would need to try and build your own Tomcat image (using a [similar tomcat Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/tomcat/blob/1722fc14b4eb66f746a2067739f32d4111f408de/7/jre7-alpine/Dockerfile)) to be sure to run the exact Tomcat version you want.
See also "[Dockerfile for tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27733476/6309)" as an example.